# Android: App automatically coming to foreground up on starting an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, background, foreground

I have a signup flow in my app. Post successful signup I start an activity (Async network call). During the signup process which takes some 15-20 secs, if I go to some other app, my app is coming to foreground when the post-signup activity is being started.

Call in signUp fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = getActivity();
    }


   public void navigateToPostSignUp() {
    startActivity(PostSignUpActivity.newIntent(activity, false, false));
    activity.finish();
}
```

Snippet from PostSignUpActivity:

```
public static Intent newIntent(@NonNull Context context,
                                   boolean someBool1,
                                   boolean someBool2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostSignUpActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(BOOL_1, someBool1);
        intent.putExtra(BOOL_2, someBool2);
        return intent;
    }
```

Snippet from the manifest:

```
<activity
      android:name=".presentation.ui.activity.PostSignUpActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On post signup you can check whether the activity is in background or not. If the activity is in background you can show a notification or else start your activity.

You can use the following method to check whether the activity is in background.

```
public boolean isInBackground(){
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses= activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();     


for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {

    PackageInfo p = null;
    try {
        p = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appProcess.pkgList[0], PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    if(p != null && p.packageName.equals(getPackageName()) && appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){                                
        Log.d("Is in background:", "false");
        return false;
    }
}

Log.d("Is in background:", "true");
return true;}
```